# MonoTouch: Custom drawing text allways draws flip text

Tags: xamarin.ios

Inside the UIView subclass, I override the Draw sub to draw some custom text, but the text allways is drawn as flip text.

This is the code I am using:

```
class TextViewProblem : UIView
{
public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

        UIColor.White.SetFill();

        g.SelectFont("Arial",16f,CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);

        UIColor.White.SetFill();
        g.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        g.ShowTextAtPoint(1,25,"Yiannis 123");



    }

}
```

And this is the output of  this code:
[image]

Why is the text drawn flipped?

I am running:
MonoDevelop 2.4.2
iPhone Simulator 4.2
MonoTouch 3.2.6

You can download a project to reproduce this issue from this link: [www.grbytes.com/downloads/TextProblem.zip](http://www.grbytes.com/downloads/TextProblem.zip)

Comment: I found that inside the Draw override I can use the DrawString method of the UIView. It draws the text fine this way.

Answer (score 10):

The image is flipped because the coordinate system for CoreGraphics is not the same as for UIKit, you need to apply a transformation that includes flipping around the rendering (scale by x=1, y=-1) and then translate by the height (x=0, y=height).

You do this by applying the transformation to your graphics context.

Comment: I've tried this with no success:
gctx.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
gctx.TranslateCTM(0, this.Frame.Width);

Comment: I also tried g.ScaleCTM(1, -1);g.TranslateCTM(0, this.Frame.Height); but it is not working. I get a black UIView

Comment: first translate and then scale

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that works:

```
        CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        UIColor.White.SetFill();
        g.ScaleCTM(1f,-1f);
        g.SelectFont("Arial",16f,CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        UIColor.White.SetFill();
        g.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        g.ShowTextAtPoint(1,-50,"Yiannis 123");
```

Once you set the scale to -1 for Y, now your coordinate system is upside down. So (0,0) is top left, but bottom left is now (0,-480), not (0,480). So note the -50 in `ShowTextAtPoint`.

Comment: You have set the fill twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()) {
            g.ScaleCTM (1f, -1f);
            g.TranslateCTM (0, -Bounds.Height);
               ....
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works fine:

```
public override void Draw (System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

        g.TranslateCTM(0,Bounds.Height);
        g.ScaleCTM(1f,-1f);
        g.DrawImage ..........
    }
```

The tip is: first TranslateCTM and then ScaleCTM.